# Basic Math Equation

Tags: math, equation

`y=0` and `x=0`

Both increment by `1` every millisecond, but `x=0` whenever it reaches `120`.

What is the equation for finding `x` if `y` is... `5000`?

Comment: Do they not teach modulus in schools these days?

Comment: it's literally a math problem...

Comment: I imagine they do ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be entirely a math problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x = y % 120

% is called modulus

Comment: Wonderufl, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You just use modulus.

```
(y / 120) + (y % 120) = x
```